# Help with Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is the sequence ($x_n$)= $a^n(n^2)$ , $0<a<1$ convergent?

Proof that the sequence is unbounded and hence divergent:

Assume it is bounded, then there exists $M>0$, such that $M\geq|x_n|$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$. We note that since $a>0$ and $n>0$, all the terms of the sequence are positive. So $M\geq x_n$. Since $a^n$ is positive, then its reciprocal must also be positive. Hence by multiplying both sides by $1/a^n$, we obtain $M/a^n\geq n^2$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$.

By the Archimedean property, there exists $n_1 \geq M/a^n$, since $M/a^n$ is positive. Let $n_2 = n_1 +1$. Then $n_2$ is a natural number, and $n_2 > M/a^n$, so
$$
n_2^2 > n_2  M/a^n > n_1 M/ a^n \geq M/ a^n 
$$
so $n_2^2 > M/ a^n$. But then $M/a^n \geq n_2^2$ since $n_2 \in \Bbb N$. Since $n_2^2$ cannot be more than $M/a^n$ and less than or equal to $M/a^n$ at the same time, we have derived a contradiction and hence the sequence is unbounded.

Proof that the sequence converges:
We employ the Cauchy ratio test.

Take the ratio $x_{n+1} / x_n$. We obtain
$$
(a^{n+1} (n+1)^2)/a^n n^2 = a(n+1)^2 / n^2 = a(n^2/n^2 +2n/n^2 + 1/n^2) = a(1+2/n+ 1/n^2).$$
Since the sequences $1/n^2$ and $1/n$ both converge to $0$, the sequence converges to $a(1)+ a(2)(0)+a(0)= a$. Since $a<1$, then the sequence converges.

Could someone help me, which of these proofs is false? Am I making any mistakes, any areas I can improve on? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure it's divergent? Consider a concrete example, maybe $a=1/10$ or $a=1/2$. What do terms look like for larger $n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first proof is wrong. When it says "but then $M/a^n\ge n_2^2$ since $n_2\in\mathbb N$" it's taking the true proposition
$$\forall n\in\mathbb N:M/a^n\ge n^2$$
and then substituting $n_2$ for $n$ *only in one of the two places*, which is not allowed. The sequence $(x_n)$ is indeed convergent to $0$.

Comment: Certainly the error is in the first part since $x_n \to 0$, but for this step I think OP is concluding $M/a^n \geq n_2^2$ because in the paragraph above, from the boundedness assumption, they conclude $M/a^n \geq n^2$ for all natural numbers $n$. Since $n_2^2 \in \mathbb{N}$, the claim follows.

Comment: @DerekAllums the $n$ and $n_2$ in $M/a^n\ge n_2^2$ are **not identical**.

Comment: I'm aware. But to repeat by comment above: the logic they used was that $M/a^n \geq n^2$ holds *for all* $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and since $n_2^2$ is indeed a natural number, then it holds for $n_2^2$ as well.

Edit: after your edit I agree you've found the issue with the first proof.

Comment: @DerekAllums indeed, I am correct now!

Comment: Agreed, looks good, +1